# CSS :hover:after Delay

Tags: html, css, hover, pseudo-element

I have this CSS:

```
.edit:hover:after{
    content: '✐';
}
```

I want the user to place the cursor on .edit class for 2 seconds before the content appears.

I've tried with this kind of aproach and doesn't work:

```
.edit:hover{
    -webkit-transition: 2s all;   
    -webkit-transition-delay: 2s; 
    -moz-transition: 2s all;   
    -moz-transition-delay: 2s; 
    -ms-transition: .2s all;   
    -ms-transition-delay: 2s; 
    -o-transition: 2s all;   
    -o-transition-delay: 2s; 
    transition: 2s all;   
    transition-delay: 2s; 
}
```

Also tried same code on `.edit:hover:after` and `.edit`.

The html is a simple `<td class='edit'>` element.

Is this possible with only css?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to put the transition on your after instead:

```css
.test:after {
  content: 'shown after 2 seconds';
  opacity:0;
  transition: 2s all;   
}

.test:hover:after {
  opacity:1;
  transition-delay: 2s; 
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  hover me for 2 seconds
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution, it works very well. I had to add :before{content:"✐";opacity:0;} for it to center properly, but i can live with that. Tomorrow i'll mark this as the correct answer

Comment: Your code also gives a 2 seconds delay before the text vanishes. Is there a way to remove that delay?

Comment: @GuillaumeF. there is no delay before the fade out - it happens as soon as you remove your mouse - try reducing the length of the transition if you want to speed it up